# Composition of functions and concavity

Tags: convex-analysis, function-and-relation-composition

Suppose that function $h : [0,1]^n \to \mathbb R$ is concave and non-decreasing and that function $g:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ is concave. Define:

$$ f(x_1,\dots, x_n)=h\left(g(x_1),\dots,g(x_n)\right) $$

Is it true that $f$ is concave?

According to page 86 of Boyd and Vandenberghe [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook), vector decomposition exhibits:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

However, here, function $g$ need not be twice differentiable. Any hint on how to prove this claim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the definition of concave:
$$f((1-\alpha )x+\alpha y)\geq (1-\alpha ) f(x)+\alpha f(y)$$
So in this case you would show
$$h(g((1-\alpha)x_1+\alpha y_1),...,g((1-\alpha)x_n+\alpha y_n))$$
$$\ge h((1-\alpha)g(x_1)+\alpha g(y_1),...,(1-\alpha)g(x_n)+\alpha g(y_n))$$
$$\ge (1-\alpha)h(g(x_1),...,g(x_n))+\alpha h(g(y_1),...,g(y_n)))$$
using the facts that h is non-decreasing and concave, respectively.